# App that overlays a video frame when recording another video

Tags: video, video-editing, video-recording

This might be very specific but I am sure it exists.

There are cameras and apps for multiexposure that put a transparent overlay of your last picture on the screen so you can better align your next shot (not including the overlay in the actual recorded image afterwards).

I am looking for the same thing but preferably as an ios mobile or windows 10 app for recording videos. What I want to do is record a video. And later record a second video that has to have lots of things aligned the same way as the video before it had. The best help here would be an overlay of the last frame of the previous video. 
Is there any app that can pull this off?